# Read a list of bad UTF data from a file in python and compare it with a line

Tags: python, python-2.6

Let's  I have this sequence of characters

```
>>> '\xed\xba\xbd'
'íº½'
```

My `conf_file` contains the list of these strings which have to be compared if they are present in a line and has to be excluded.

```
$cat excl_char_seq.lst
\xed\xba\xbd
\xed\xa9\x81
\xed\xba\x91
```

Here is my code to compare if a line contains any of these sequences.

```
v_conf_file = 'excl_char_seq.lst'   
with open(v_conf_file) as f:
     seqlist = f.read().splitlines()
line = 'weríº½66'
print ([ 1 for seqs in seqlist if seqs in line ])
```

But the printed list from the above code is **empty**.

When I printed the seqlist, I got the following output, which seems to have escaped the sequence with a "\".

```
['\\xed\\xba\\xbd', '\\xed\\xa9\\x81', '\\xed\\xba\\x91' ]
```

How should I correct the code for it to match the line with the file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the line you have read from the file actually contains 12 characters: `\`, `x`, `e`, `d`, `\`, `x`, `b`, `a`, `\`, `x`, `b` and `d`, and you want to convert that to 3 characters `'\xed'`, '`\xba'` and '`\xbd'`. Regexes could help here to identify *escaped* characters starting with `\x`:

```
def unescape(string):
    rx = re.compile(r'(\\x((?:[0-9a-fA-F]){2}))')
    while True:
        m = rx.search(string)
        if m is None: return string
        string = string.replace(m.group(1), chr(int(m.group(2), 16)))
```

You can use it to preprocess the lines that you extract from the file (do not forget to import `re` module):

```
v_conf_file = 'excl_char_seq.lst'   
with open(v_conf_file) as f:
     seqlist = [ unescape(line.strip()) for line in fd ]
line = 'weríº½66'
print ([ 1 for seqs in seqlist if seqs in line ])
```

When I controlled the content of `seqlist`, I got as expected:

```
>>> print seqlist
['\xed\xba\xbd', '\xed\xa9\x81', '\xed\xba\x91']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have to try this.. will come back.